# Mod_rewrite not redirecting for exact Query String

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone advise why this doesn't seem to work?

I am trying to redirect http://domain.com/?feed=rss2 to http://domain.com/wp-content/staticfeed/rss2.xml

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} feed=rss2
RewriteRule ^/$ /wp-content/staticfeed/rss2.xml [L,T=application/rss+xml]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^feed=rss2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/staticfeed/rss2.xml [L]
```

Comment: if you're getting a 500 error is something being logged in the Apache error log? Could you give details?

Comment: Sure: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^(?feed=rss2)$'

Comment: "Rakesh - this is what I get with your most recent one: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Please remove "()" from the above query-string and see if it works.

Comment: There is no "?" symbol in the rule that will fail as said. But I am sure internal redirects occurs only when the process goes recursive. I don't see anything that is recursive here. Wish there was a live-editor which helps me see it :-)